# How do I completely uninstall Python and all its packages?

Tags: python, package, uninstallation

I installed some packages , but I think either some of the packages corrupted or are conflicting with versions

Is there a good way to just uninstall every package and python itself?

Comment: How to do that would depend on how it was installed, what system you are using. You didn't tell us any of that.

Comment: try to reinstall without uninstall?

Comment: I accidentally yum uninstalled python once, and since yum depends on python, it happily uninstalled itself too. Oops.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove all the packages you've installed (as opposed to all of Python), you'd want to nuke your `site-packages` directory.

To find it, from Python run `>>> import some_package` (where `some_package` is a package you've installed; `setuptools` is one you're likely to have), then run `some_package.__file__`. The output should be something like `/path/to/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.6.egg/setuptools/__init__.pyc`. Delete (or, better yet, rename) and recreate `/path/to/site-packages`. That will get rid of everything you've installed.

Comment: Check `site.py` in the same folder as `site-packages` to see whether you need to comment things out as well.